# Trying to combine three tables base on my situation mysql php?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to connect three table. The output will be like this: Get fruit match price 4 first on table_1 and exclude any fruit with mark 6 on table_2, then at last, on table_3, if the fruit factor match, then get the value of val, if not, I still keep the fruit with val NULL value. I was thinking JOIN, but not so sure how to combine three tables to do what i want. Help, appreciate.

```
<?php
/*
table_1
fruit  price
apple   4
banana  5
pear    4

table_2
fruit   mark
apple    5
banana   4
pear     6

table_3
fruit   factor  val
apple    56     good
banana   89     good
pear     56      bad
*/
$sql = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("
SELECT a.fruit, b.fruit, c.fruit, c.val 
FROM table_1 a, table_2 b, table_3 c WHERE a.price = %d AND b.fruit NOT IN
 ( SELECT fruit FROM table_2 WHERE mark =%d ) AND c.fruit = a.fruit OR c.factor = %d
            ",$price,$mark,%factor));

foreach($sql as $sqls){ 
     $result1 = $sqls-> a.fruit;
     $result2 = $sqls-> c.val;              
     $result[] = array($result1=>$result2);
            }

?>
```

Comment: You need to learn about joins... https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

Comment: First, don't need to put php codes in a snippet.  Second, it's clear you are not familiar with JOIN. So, if someone answered you, you won't be able to do it in next time. I strongly recommend you learn about JOIN, refactor your query, if you still had any problem, ask here. we help you.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: you're also mixing `and` and `or` without `()` to enforce the parse order. you will undoubtedly get weird results

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 
a.fruit,b.mark,c.factor,c.value
from table_1 a,
left join table_2 b
 on b.fruit=a.fruit and b.mark != 6
left join table_3 c
 on c.fruit=a.fruit
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!